# Can you explain "lock your local display and not the remote one" by ssh?

Tags: ssh, screensaver, xscreensaver

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505644/674

> if you run `light-locker` through SSH on the remote machine, it will lock your local display and not the remote one (just as running gnome-terminal or any other command will run it on the remote machine but display it locally).

I am not sure what "lock your local display and not the remote one" means.

To see what happens, can someone show me what commands I shall run to "run `light-locker` through SSH on the remote machine"?

Note that I do not necessarily run `light-locker`, I now use `xscreensaver` as screen saver and locker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is confusing, but from their example I can decode it.

They are saying that if you are logged into an X11 session, and ssh to another (remote) machine [With the `-X` option]. Then any program that you run, will run on this remote machine, but any X11 program will display on your local machine. Similarly any lock program will lock your X11 Display (on the local machine).

---

If you wanted to lock one of the displays of a remote machine, then you would have to set the DISPLAY variable accordingly, and configure `xauth` appropriately (but that is another question).